# Linux sound is pitched and slowed down when going through the sound card of a mixer controller

Tags: debian, audio, kde, pulseaudio, alsa

When I connect my mixer to my Debian/KDE machine the sound is slowed and pitched down. Sometimes it takes days or weeks until this effect occurs.

Strangely it rarely works after restarting the mixer console. It usually works after restarting it many times.

Once it works I can change the sound output under "Audio Volume" back and forth and it keeps working.
I think it's skewing the sound more often than previously and that I need way more restarts to get it working but I might be wrong.

I already checked if there is a firmware update for my mixer console but it's already the latest version. And I tried changing the Phonon Backend from Phonon VLC to Phonon GStreamer but that didn't help. `/var/log/syslog` doesn't seem to have useful messages that are related to the problem.

It's a HID controller (USB, not MIDI) with an onboard soundcard and I'm using ALSA. `aplay -l` says the driver is module-alsa-card.c.

Any ideas what might cause this (or how to find out) and how it could be fixed?

Comment: How new is your mixer console? What model is it and what driver are you using? For any vaguely professional audio hardware, I would strongly consider using JACK, rather than Pulseaudio, as it should provide higher performance and lower latency.

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to specify the model. I added some more info to the question. I'm not sure if JACK can be used for HID devices. So far it doesn't look like it can. Thanks.

Comment: If you are using ALSA, then you should probably remove the 'pulseaudio' tag, as it would seem not to be relevant. I'm not 100% sure what you mean by 'it's an HID controller with an onboard soundcard'. In my experience, HID typically refers to things like mice, gamepads, etc. Do you mean it is USB? I have an external USB audio interface that I use for recording and it works fine with JACK. Tbh, I think it is going to limit people's ability to help somewhat, if you can't be more specific about what the hardware is.

Comment: I think I'm using both pulseaudio and ALSA. I ran `pactl list` and `aplay -l`. The latter says the driver is module-alsa-card.c. The former also lists my controller under (playback) as usb audio. The difference between HID and MIDI is the pull and push method of retrieving data. Yes, it's USB. As of right now I'm not sure how to configure the sound output to use JACK in KDE. After a restart the sound is working properly again but the problem will reappear.

Comment: ALSA is the lowest level sound server in Linux, which is built into the kernel and contains the device drivers. Pulseaudio and JACK are user-space sound servers that run on top of ALSA and interface with it. Applications can be built/configured to use pulse, JACK or just run on ALSA directly. So, support for the sound servers depends on the application you are running - some might be able to choose between all 3, others might only be compatible with 1 or 2 of them.

Comment: I don't have experience with Phonon or KDE, so I may not be qualified to help much more. It looks like [Gstreamer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GStreamer) should be going straight to ALSA, in which case, if you are using that backend, it should bypass pulseaudio (you could try disabling the pulseaudio server just to make sure). Are you having similar issues with any other audio applications, besides Phonon? Conversely, do you experience it with other audio hardware (e.g. built-in sound card), or just that device?

Comment: I get this problem when I open a sound file like an mp3 with a player like VLC. I have two sound-related system options in KDE: "Audio Volume" and (Phonon) "Audio and Video". I have this problem with the mixer controller only. However, I think last time I connected my headphones directly to my computer instead of the mixer controller had the music a bit too fast instead of too slow. That never happened before and only occurred after many restarts of the controller and it was only slightly faster (I'm 60-80% sure that it was too fast).Besides GStreamer & controller=output it's default settings.

Comment: This is starting to get into an 'extended discussion', but what I would try is this: install LXDE (so you're not using Phonon) and try audio with the suspect device in there. Try it with a couple of audio apps straight to ALSA (i.e. disable or uninstall pulseaudio). If you get issues with just that device and not others, then it probably suggests an issue with the driver support in ALSA. Also, I think some of the information you have shared in cmments should probably be added to the question.

Comment: slowed and pitched down = sample rate is wrong. To debug, use the "divide and conquer" approach: Separate your audio pipeline into parts, test each part by itself. I.e.: Connect your mixer, make sure you see the effect. Stop Pulseaudio (`pulseaudio --kill`), find a WAV file, use `aplay` to play it directly via ALSA. Still see the effect? Then it's somewhere in the ALSA drivers and/or hardware, so start diffing there. Don't see the effect? Restart Pulseaudio, use `paplay` to test it. Don't see the effect? Use you Phonon backend. Etc.

Comment: Thanks, that might be useful - debugging would already be half the solution. The problem with that is that it only happens after a few days or even weeks. I don't know how to make the effect show up and how to check whether it's still there at a level which I couldn't detect just by listening. I'll probably try this for weeks later if I can't find further information. Are you sure it's the sample-rate? (Music is slower, lower-freq).

Comment: @dirkt When I quit pulseaudio like that it immediately restarts except when doing [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1199456) (but then no audio can be played...incl with aplay). It still occurs when playing the file with `aplay` (only through the mixer not through internal sound hardware; same with paplay). I don't know what else one could test and whether it's something in the ALSA drivers (and if so where to file a bug with which info). The error will disappear when I reboot or earlier, restarting the mixer a few times didn't solve it so far.

Comment: For now the issue is here: https://github.com/alsa-project/alsa-firmware/issues/7 but that may be the wrong place and insufficient info.